# Disable Save button in jquery, to avoid multiple submittion but should call server side code

Tags: c#, html, jquery, dom

I have a portal created on MVC, When 'Save' button is clicked it calls ' `public IActionResult OnPost(string participantIds)'` method and creates a record in CRM, On multiple click of 'Save' button multiple records are created. I want to disable Save button after user clicks on it once. If i do so, It does not create record in CRM, Below is the existing .js code

```
$(".save").click(function () {
    finished = true;
    window.location.hash = '';
});
```

I updated it to:

```
$(".save").click(function () {
    $('.save').prop('value', 'Saving...');
    $('.save').prop('disabled', true);
    finished = true;
    window.location.hash = '';
});
```

Now it does not call `OnPost()` method but disables the button and change label to Saving..
I want it to get disabled and create record in CRM.
My HTML looks like below:

```
 <div class="text-right">
            <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary save" value="@localizer.GetString("Save")" />
    </div>
```